# React Suite Textarea not working properly in Form with validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rsuite

I am using [React Suite](https://rsuitejs.com/) to build a page with a text area in it. I am using the [Form Validation](https://rsuitejs.com/components/form-validation/) feature in the library and I have to use a text-area.

#### Context

Following the [examples on custom control validation](https://rsuitejs.com/components/form-validation/#custom-form-control) and the [examples on how to create a text area control](https://rsuitejs.com/components/input/#textarea), I built the following:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Input, Form, Schema } from "rsuite";

const App = () => {
  const [formValue, setFormValue] = React.useState({ desc: "" });

  const model = Schema.Model({
    desc: Schema.Types.StringType().isRequired("required"),
  });

  const TextArea = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <Input {...props} as="textarea" ref={ref} />
  ));

  const formRef = React.useRef();

  return (
    <>
      <Form
        model={model}
        formValue={formValue}
        onChange={setFormValue}
        ref={formRef}
      >
        <Input as="textarea" rows={3} placeholder="Textarea1" />
        <Form.Control
          name="desc"
          placeholder="Form textarea"
          accepter={TextArea}
        />
      </Form>
    </>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

There is a [CodeBox available for reproing this](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/festive-snowflake-9c8r29?file=%2Findex.js).

#### The problem

However, when I run it, all renders fine, but the text box using the `Form.Control` has a weird behavior on input, where only one char at a time can be added. The first text area has a normal behavior.

Comment: Seems like I forgot to publish the sandbox, sorry. I updated the link now

Answer (score 0):

Of course I need to create the `forwardRef` outside the component otherwise it re-creates the component at every re-render:

```
const TextArea = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <Input {...props} as="textarea" ref={ref} />
));

const App = () => { ... }
```